# How to affect child form from parent form in mdi c#

Tags: c#

My problem is that I have created child's object and show child first time. but when second time I just want to change value of child's label from parent but don't want to show another form.
Here is my code.

First time

```
ChildForm ObjChild = new ChildForm("Hi");
ObjChild.Show();
```

On second time I just want to set Bye in place of Hi.

```
ChildForm ObjChild = new ChildForm("H!");
ObjChild.BringToFront();
```

Because child form is already opened.
This is my child Form

```
public Form1(string p_Param)
{
InitializeComponent();
Label1.Text = p_Param;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructors call one time when object created. You must implement a new public void or function rather than a constructor to do that.

```
public void ChangeLabelText(string txt)
{
Label1.Text=txt;
}
```

**EDIT:**

In your parent form;
Out of functions;

```
chilFrm ChildForm;
```

Inside any function;

```
if (chilFrm == null)
{
    chilFrm = new ChildForm();
    chilFrm.TopLevel = false;
    chilFrm.Parent = this;
    chilFrm.StartUpProsecc("Created New");
    chilFrm.Show();
}
else
{
    chilFrm.StartUpProsecc("Showed the existing.");
    chilFrm.BringToFront();
}
```

Comment: and Should I call this function from parent?

Comment: Yes. You can call a public function from anywhere you want when you created an instance of that class.

Comment: I tried this in parent 


ChildForm ChilFrm = new ChildForm ();

System.Windows.Forms.Form UD = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["ChildForm "];
if (((ChildForm )UD) != null)
{
                //open Form
                ChilFrm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  ChilFrm.StartUpProsecc("Hi");
                ChilFrm.BringToFront();                
}
else
{
  ChilFrm.StartUpProsecc("Hi");
                ChilFrm.Show();
}

Comment: public void StartUpProsecc(string p_Param)
        {
            Label1.Text = p_Param;
        }

Comment: in parent; write this statement out of functions so make it global; ChildForm chilFrm; Then you can make your call from inside other functions. Your code is this => if (chilFrm == null) { chilFrm = new ChildForm();} chilFrm.Show(); chilFrm.StartUpProsecc("Hi");

Comment: My form(child form) is already shown. I want to set value second time when my child is shown already. that time I just want to set value and take child BringTofront.

Comment: Can U tell me If I want to use Child form out of parent Form?

Comment: No problem. One more thing. If you close your childform with X on that, the childform disposes. so this code is for one time use. if you want to occur everytime. Write your childform's FormClosing event this: e.Cancel = true; this.Hide(); and add this line above to bringtofront statement: this.Show();

Comment: hhmmmm.. Thanks one again. I think You may do some work for giving me answer? thanks.

Comment: No problem bro. I remember my learning process too that's it :)